# Replace For-Loop to speed up code

Tags: performance-tuning

I need to speed up this code

```
X = PauliMatrix[1];
Y = PauliMatrix[2];
Z = PauliMatrix[3];
t = π/2;
n = 4;
psi = (1/Sqrt[2^n])*{{1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {-1}, {1}, {1}, {1},{-1}, {1}, {-1}, {-1}, {1}};  

For[θ = π/180, θ < π, θ += π/180,  
   For[ϕ = -π + π/180, ϕ <= π, ϕ += π/180,  
      CT = CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian","Mapping", {1, θ, ϕ}];  
      x = CT[[1]]; y = CT[[2]]; z = CT[[3]];  
      U = Cos[t]*IdentityMatrix[2] + I*Sin[t]*(x*X + y*Y + z*Z);
      Uall = KroneckerProduct[U, U, U, U];
      If[Abs[Total[(Transpose[psi].(Uall.psi))[[1]]]] >= .999,Print[N[U] // MatrixForm]]
   ]
]
```

I just started using *Mathematica* last week.  The code works the way I want it to, but it takes about 20 minutes to run.  I just need help speeding up this code.

Edit: I am trying to loop over points on the unit sphere as spherical coordinates. Then transform those points into Cartesian coordinates, then use those to create 2x2 matrices.  Then do the kronecker product of that matrix n times.  Lastly the If statement is to test if how far off Uall*psi is to equaling psi.

Comment: In the code snippet here, psi is undefined.

Comment: It might be easier to come up with something neater if you'll explain what you're trying to do here with your code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is to localized and is not likely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how `psi` is defined, I can't fully answer, but a few points.

Try to avoid `For` loops and use `Do` instead.  So instead of writing

```
For[θ = π/180, θ < π, θ += π/180, 
For[ϕ = -π + π/180, ϕ <= π, ϕ += π/180,
  (* some code here *)
   ]
]
```

write

```
Do[
  (* some code here *)
  , {θ, π/180, π, π/180}
  , {ϕ, -π + π/180, π, π/180}]
```

Next, there's no reason to populate `CT`, `x`, `U`, and `Uall` at every iteration of the loop.  Without defining any of the variables, you can enter the following code before the loop begins:

```
CT = CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
  "Mapping", {1, θ, ϕ}];
x = CT[[1]]; y = CT[[2]]; z = CT[[3]];
U = Cos[t]*IdentityMatrix[2] + I*Sin[t]*(x*X + y*Y + z*Z);
Uall = KroneckerProduct[U, U, U, U];
```

This stores `Uall` as a symbolic matrix.  Then you can build up the inner product as a compiled function to do everything much quicker.

This should be faster, hopefully it does what you need:

```
X = PauliMatrix[1];
Y = PauliMatrix[2];
Z = PauliMatrix[3];
t = π/2;
n = 4;
psi = Flatten[(1/
  Sqrt[2.0^
    n])*{{1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {-1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, \
{-1}, {1}, {-1}, {-1}, {1}}];
CT = CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
  "Mapping", {1, θ, ϕ}];
x = CT[[1]]; y = CT[[2]]; z = CT[[3]];
U = Cos[t]*IdentityMatrix[2] + I*Sin[t]*(x*X + y*Y + z*Z);
Uall = KroneckerProduct[U, U, U, U];
innerproduct = Compile[{{θ, _Real}, {ϕ, _Real}},
  Evaluate[Abs[(psi.(Uall.psi))]]
  ];
Do[
If[innerproduct[θ, ϕ] >= .999, 
  Print[N[U] // MatrixForm]]
, {θ, π/180, π, π/
  180.0}, {ϕ, -π + π/180, π, π/180.0}]
```

Comment: this works a lot faster, but the output is not the same as my original code

Comment: I might be missing your point, but your first suggestion intrigued me: on what grounds should replacing `For` with `Do` speed up the code?

Comment: Never mind the outputs are the same

Comment: @MarcoB It's not that it speeds up the code, just makes it more Mathematica and less C or Fortran.  Also, easier to read

Comment: I think `Table[]` would be more appropriate here than `Do[]`, actually.

Comment: I definitely agree, I would use a table to maintain a list of the expectation value of the `Uall` operator for all values of theta and phi. I just used `Do` to recreate what OP was doing before.

Comment: But if you want a list that matches the `Print` output here, a `Reap` and `Sow` is the best way.